# Change extension of webpage but keep search results

Tags: web, hosting, url-routing

There is a website that I designed as a standard, static website with pages that I update as required.  All pages are *.html and I have some quite good google rankings.

I'm currently re-writing this site to add a CMS at the backend, this will either change all of the pages to end *.php or to use routes (which is more likely).

How can I change the site but keep existing links and search results?

e.g. If I have a link to `www.mySite.com/myPage.html`, but in the future this will be `www.mySite.com/myPage` how do I do this without breaking all links to myPage.html?

My hosting is LAMP at the moment, could this be done by altering the .htaccess file?

Answer (score 1):

[mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html) should do the job. You just put something like this in your `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1 [L,R=permanent]
```

This will cause all requests to `www.example.com/yourpage.html` to be rewritten to `www.example.com/yourpage`. The `R=permanent` part causes a permanent redirect reply to be sent to the client, which should cause well-behaved search engines to update their entries.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a play with this locally and see if it works as it should.